What does each part of a composition mean and do they makeup different “melodic pieces” (theme, subject)?: riff, lick, motif, phrase, ostinato
So basically, how many bars are each of these words and how many notes are typically in each part, and, are there more pieces that i’m missing? Like say we have a lick/riff is the smallest unit of a motif, then the motif is part of a phrase, then a phrase is a completed melodic subject, and then a composition has multiple melodic subjects. Correct me where i’m wrong!

You’re wrong in thinking there’s an answer to this that is organized and consistent. There are no strict definitions for any of these terms.

My guess is that you didn't do any 'homework'. Had you done so, you'd understand that some are synonymous.

@Tim Well as todd said supposedly there are no strict definitions which is why I came here with the question. I keep coming across different sources (books and online) using the terms slightly different.

Fair enough - that's pretty well the answer - nothing etched in stone.

@ToddWilcox Surely there are commonly accepted definitions for motif (a characteristic short part of a thema), phrase (the musical equivalent of a sentence, a more or less complete, connected musical unit) and ostinato (ongoing repetition of some musical idea, usually in accompaniment). While these might be worded differently in different cases I think the underlying idea is quite clear. But then things like “how many x are in y” do usually make little sense (except for things like classical form with 4 bars to a phrase).

@Lazy “Commonly accepted” - eh, yeah we could come up with some things. “Strict” - no. As the asker themselves commented, “I keep coming across different sources (books and online) using the terms slightly different”.

Some of these words work in very different ways than others. And part of the misunderstanding is that, while you might call all of them "units" or "building blocks," they might be used in ways other than "end to end," linearly. Let's take them one at a time:

"Riff"/"lick": these are very informal words, and informally defined. They come mostly from jazz backgrounds. They're usually used with melodic material, and can be understood as simply as "a group of notes." The size of that group is not formally defined, but these words are usually used of material that is shorter than a full "melody." The group of notes that they reference is usually related by boundaries of time or pitch: a "gesture," a group of notes that relate to each other because other groups are farther away in pitch or are separated by some time. In other words: it's nothing official, but these words are often used for short melodic gestures from a few notes to a few bars.
"Motif": This word is similar, in some ways. But it comes from more of a classical background, and it used more for structural analysis. That is, like "riff" and "lick," it's used for "shapes," however one identifies them, but it also focuses on how they get reused and work together. These could be quite short, or they could be longer. Wagner famously used "leitmotifs" to stand for certain characters or ideas, and these could be essentially full-blown melodies. John Williams copied the idea in Star Wars, so that Princess Leia or Darth Vader get their own "motifs" that might each be themes in their own right, dozens of bars long. On the other hand, the first movement of Beethoven's fifth symphony is built around a pattern of three notes, and that also would be a "motif." It would also be reasonable for a jazzer to call this pattern a "riff" or "lick," but the difference with "motif" is that we can spot that pattern throughout the movement. A "riff" or "lick" might happen just once during a solo, but the point of a "motif" is that it recurs.
"Phrase" is very much a structural word. Much like the way it's used for spoken language, it can also be a bit vague. It basically means "a chunk of musical material that belongs together and can be thought of as a single unit," for whatever reason makes sense to the person using the word. These reasons usually involve analysis of the musical "grammar": maybe something is a "phrase" because it ends with a cadence. Or maybe because it groups notes into a "shape" that mirrors some other phrase. A "phrase" tends (tends) to be more than just two or three notes, partly because it's hard to make analytical observations about such small chunks. Again, this is not an official rule, but you tend to see it more used for a few bars at a time. And phrases can combine to make bigger phrases: you could have a 16-bar phrase made of two 4-bar phrases and one 8-bar phrase. Note, while the previous words mostly analyzed linear melodic material, this one looks at the music as a whole. A big band might have lots of "riffs" happening at the same time, stacked up. But a "phrase" is typically a single chunk of time. (Typically. But also one voice could overlap its phrase with another voice's.) And although a phrase can be determined just by looking at one melody, it can also often be determined by looking at how all the voices work together to make harmonic motion.
"Ostinato" is the least vague and most clearly defined of all these terms. It just means "a pattern that repeats over and over, unchanged, throughout the piece." In Ravel's Bolero, the snare drum plays a rhythmic pattern and repeats it unaltered many times from beginning to end (below). Another example would be the simple piano duet "Heart and Soul"; the "accompaniment" part repeats the same chordal pattern while the melody is overlaid on them.





+1 and you might consider submitting some of these to the currently-empty 'phrase' tag wiki!
